# Jquery update variable through $.GET page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var p = 1;
var flag = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if(flag == 0){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            $.get('/fetchMore.php?page=' + p, function(data){});
                    p++
            }
    }
});
```

I have a page, when scroll down, page will use $.get to fetch more data into it.

in my fetchMore.php I have set up if no more data, $flag==1, I need out put javascript to update var flag, so scroll function will not fetch anymore

My question is how to update var flag from fetMore.php page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change javascript variable directly from php called by ajax. You can probably pass an empty data when no more data is available and check if data is empty in javascript and assign flag to 1

When flag is assigned 1, it will never fetch any more.

```
var p = 1;
var flag = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if(flag == 0){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            $.get('/fetchMore.php?page=' + p, function(data){
                if(data == {} || data == [] || data == "") {
                    flag = 1;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `echo` something from your PHP script it is received by the JS which made a request to it so :

`echo $flag` from your php script and then:

```
$.get('/fetchMore.php?page=' + p, function(data){
    if(data == 1) {
       flag = 1
    }
}
```

you might want to check in your php script if data is available or not..

```
if(!$data.length){
    // there is no more data
    echo "1"; // or something more useful
    exit(); // this stops further execution of the script
}
// if there is data the script will continue to run and you can echo or do anything else later..
```